# Классификатор К-ближайших соседей

Tags: python, машинное-обучение

Только начал изучать машинное обучение.
Для многих это наверное тривиальный пример, но я не могу понять, почему, при k=1, зеленая область на синем поле - это плохо?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А вот эта же точка,при k=5, уже находится в синей области и это гуд, но почему, увы, додуматься я не могу. А на просторах интернета понятного объяснения не нашел.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я понимаю, что цветные области - это границы принятия решения, который зависят от выбранной метрики расстояния(в данном случае L2). Вопрос зачем эти области? Чтобы визуализировать сколько данных занимает каждая выборка? Тогда почему в синей(к примеру) выборке, при k=5, выборка состоит из не только синих данных, а вот, при k=1, только из синих, но по площади она меньше? не понятно..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Задачи классификации для машинного обучения решают проблему того, как имея массив объектов, для которых уже размечено, к какой группе относится каждый объект, предсказать к какой группе будет относится новый объект, для которого это пока не известно.

Но между параметрами объектов и их принадлежностью к группе не всегда есть чёткая и однозначная связь. Кроме этого на реальных данных почти всегда присутствует влияние каких-то случайных факторов.
Из-за этого на реальных данных часто присутствуют "выбросы" - такие элементы, которые реально относятся к одной группе, но по свои характеристикам больше похоже на элементы другой группы.

И если построенная модель будет слишком чуткой к каждому отдельному элементы, то в окрестностях выбросов она будет ошибаться. Поэтому хорошая модель умеет усреднять и обобщать закономерности, и тогда одиночные выбросы не будут вводить её в заблуждение.

Больше вы можете найти в любом поисковике по запросу "проблема переобучения в машинном обучении".

Answer (score 3):

Александр дал вам исчерпывающий ответ, объясняющий проблему переобучения модели. Эта проблема хорошо заметна на первом рисунке.

Дополню его ответ ответом на вопрос:

> Вопрос зачем эти области?

Это области, при попадании *новых* (предсказываемых) точек в которые, этим точкам будет присваиваться соответствующий класс.

При обучении модели ей подается на вход обучающая выборка. Модель, обученная с `k=1`, будет иметь очень высокую точность предсказания для уже знакомых ей точек (точки, на которых ее обучали) по сравнению со второй моделью и гораздо худшую точность для незнакомых ей точек. Это как аппроксимировать набор точек на плоскости полиномом высокой степени - практически все известные точки попадут на график полинома, но предсказания где будет точки между известными точками будут очень неточными.

Нашей задачей является классификация **незнакомых** точек / данных.